One to Many doesn't remove foreign key on delete in SQLAlchemy
Here's the setup:
A User can have many images assigned (related_images), but can only have 1 profile image.
class Photo(Model):
    __tablename__ = "photo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    filepath = Column(Text)

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id], back_populates="related_images", lazy=True)

class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    
    related_images = db.relationship("Photo", foreign_keys=[Photo.user_id], back_populates="user", lazy=True, cascade="delete")

    profile_image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("photo.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    profile_image = db.relationship("Photo", foreign_keys=[profile_image_id], lazy=True, post_update=True, cascade="delete")

I want to delete a User's profile image, so I do:
user = get_user(user_id)
db.session.delete(user.profile_image)
db.session.commit()

This will successfully delete the row from the Photo table, however user.profile_image_id on the User table will still hold the old photo id, id 1 in this case.
How do I delete the user's profile photo so that it's removed (or no longer referenced) from the User table too? The ondelete and cascade='delete' don't seem to work here.

The title specifies a one-to-many relationship, but each table has an FK to the other. Please [edit] the question to clarify how you expect the relationship to behave.

Hi, I edited my question. Basically a user has related images, but only a single profile image. In order to reuse the Photo model, I need to define an FK on the User model, so that's why there are two FKs. However, the issue is when deleting the profile photo only, the FK on the User is not cleared. If this isn't the way to set up the Models, it'll be helpful for me to see what the proper model setup should be.

class Photo(Model):
tablename = "photo"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
filepath = Column(Text)

user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id], back_populates="related_images", lazy='select')

class User(Model):
tablename = "user"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = Column(Text)

related_images = db.relationship("Photo", foreign_keys=[Photo.user_id], back_populates="user", lazy='select', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

profile_image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("photo.id", ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=True)
profile_image = db.relationship("Photo", foreign_keys=[profile_image_id], lazy='joined', post_update=True, cascade="all, delete-orphan")


It's specific and to the point answer

Hi this gives the error: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: delete-orphan cascade is normally configured only on the "one" side of a one-to-many relationship, and not on the "many" side of a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship.. Can you explain what you are trying to do?
